# How to enable mod_rewrite via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cpanel

I'm going to enable mod_rewrite  (modsecurity ) in Cpanel and here is my htaccess, please advice me how to enable it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|install|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a search. http://www.ehow.com/how_8575674_enable-modrewrite-cpanel.html

Comment: Did you compile your Apache with ModRewrite module support? If you have not enabled it, you will have to run EasyApache to add support for Apache modRewrite.

Comment: Actually I did it, So even I submitted a ticket to Cpanel but no reply from them. Still I'm stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

As per your provided .HTACCESS code, mod_rewrite is already enabled..

RewriteEngine on

While Mod_security can not be enabled/disabled from cPanel end. If you have access to server OR WHM panel then you can do it and make sure you have compiled APACHE to enabl mod_security, otherwise contact your hosting provider to do it for you.
You can find APACHE compile for mod_security details from [here...](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Apache+Module%3A+ModSecurity)

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is not the same thing as mod_security. The first allows you to create custom rewrite rules in an .htaccess file like the ones you have mentioned. Mod_security is a security module for apache (protects your website against php sql injection attacks, xss etc).

mod_rewrite is enabled by default on a fresh cPanel/WHM install.

What is exactly not working on your actual config/setup?